# R For Loop Random Forest Compiling

Tags: r

Within a for loop, I want to take my dataset, subset into group IDs, run a random forest for each group (500 unique group IDs), get % var explained for each, and create one final data frame with one row for each group ID and associated % var explained. Below is my code. I know I am close because the random forests work. I can't figure out the last few steps.
FYI "results" is a data frame with the group ID and actual response only; dataframe 1 is all explanatory variables and response in all groups.

````
  ### subset datasets for each species
  dat_i <- subset(dataframe1, dataframe1$Group==unique(dataframe1$Group)[i])
  # run a random forest on each species subset
  rf.i <- randomForest(Response~., data=dat_i, proximity=TRUE)
  ## generated predicted values to compare for accuracy assessments
  dat_i$predicted <- unname(predict(rf.i, dat_i))
  dat_i$var <- 1 - (sum((dat_i$Response-dat_i$predicted)^2)/sum((dat_i$Response-mean(dat_i$Response))^2))
  # add in species variables
  combined_df <- merge(results, dat_i, by="Group")
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (I use the inbuilt `iris` dataset, since you don't provide any reproducible example):

```
    library(randomForest)
    data(iris)
    #assign group number according to Species
    iris$Group <- as.integer(iris$Species)
    dataframe1 <- iris
    #initalize a list for storing results
    var <- as.list(seq_along(unique(iris$Group)))

    for (i in seq_along(unique(iris$Group))) {
      #subset data according to groups
      dat_i <- dataframe1[dataframe1$Group==i,]
      # run a random forest on each species subset
      rf.i <- randomForest(Sepal.Length~., data=dat_i, proximity=TRUE)
      ## generated predicted values to compare for accuracy assessments
      dat_i$predicted <- unname(predict(rf.i, dat_i))
      #store results in the list
      var[[i]] <- 1 - (sum((dat_i$Sepal.Length-dat_i$predicted)^2)/sum((dat_i$Sepal.Length-mean(dat_i$Sepal.Length))^2))
    }
    #convert to data.frame
    result <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,var))
    #add Groups column
    result$Group <- seq_along(unique(iris$Group))
```

output:

```
         V1 Group
1 0.3568714     1
2 0.4507938     2
3 0.4178580     3
```